# How to always mark "Continue on Error" field in Azure DevOps release task true?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

There is a checkbox called "Continue on Error" inside Control group in any Azure DevOps build/release task. As the name suggets, it moves on to next task in the pipeline, even if the current task fails. We are developing a release task extension, and since it is not a critical one, we do not want this to be a bottleneck for the users, hence by default want to make the checkbox ticked. But we couldn't see the respective field anywhere in task.json file. Is it possible to achieve by overwriting any configs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to always mark “Continue on Error” field in Azure DevOps release task true?

You can try to set the field `"continueOnError": true,` in the `task.json` file to check if it work for you.

When I add a task, like `PowerShell Script` in the release pipeline, then a export this pipeline, check the `.json` file and find there is a field `"continueOnError": true,`:

[image]

If I import that .json file to the release pipeline, the checkbox is ticked by default.

Hope this helps.